# Guava cache - How do I loadAll on any miss?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have a use case where the method to load my cache's data is a bulk call, but I'm never going to use getAll to get data from the cache.  Is there a way to have multiple concurrent gets all block on a single loadAll?  I don't want individual gets on different keys to result in multiple calls to the data source.

```
cache.get(key1); // missing entry, starts refresh
cache.get(key2); // separate thread, already getting reloaded due to key1 miss
```

I think I'll have to implement my own synchronization after looking into the LocalCache, using something like a local cache in my data accessor that only allows a call through every so many units of time. When a call does go through, update the local copy with a single assignment statement.

Am I missing something from Guava's cache library?

**Edit:**

I'm considering something like the following.  However, it could potentially continue returning stale data while `loadAll` finishes.  I'd prefer everything blocks at `load`, and only the first request causes `loadAll` to proceed.

```
public class DataCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<String, Double>
{
    private final Cache<String, Double> cache;
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Double> currentData;
    private final AtomicBoolean isloading;

    public DataCacheLoader( final Cache<String, Double> cache )
    {
        this.cache = cache;
        isLoading = new AtomicBoolean( false );
    }

    @Override
    public Double load( final String key ) throws Exception
    {
        if ( isLoading.compareAndSet( false, true ) )
        {
            cache.putAll( loadAll( Lists.newArrayList( key ) ) ) );
        }
        return currentData.get( key );
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Double> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) throws Exception
    {
        currentData = source.getAllData();
        return currentData;
    }
}
```

Comment: just as an idea: call get(K key, Callable<? extends V> valueLoader)
 and pass a callable that will call loadAll.

Comment: Maybe do this with a `ForwardingCache`?  I'd be suspicious of recursive `CacheLoader`s, though.

Comment: I thought about the `ForwardingCache` approach.  However, for the specific use case (this is a generalization), I realized I was caching at the wrong granularity.  If I want the whole load to block, cache the whole load.  I'll leave the question since I suspect there are use cases where an approach to block everything may make sense.

Comment: I think your solution (edited) solution is on the right track. If you want everything to block then make your AtomicBoolean a volatile boolean and add a ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution that should do the trick.  The idea is that instead of caching each individual key you cache the whole map with a single fixed key.  The one drawback is that you won't be able to expire individual parts of the underlying map (at least not easily), but that may not be a requirement.

```
class MyCache {
  private static final Object KEY = new Object();
  private final LoadingCache<Object, Map<String, Double>> delegate = 
      new CacheBuilder()
      // configure cache
          .build(new CacheLoader<Object, Map<String, Double>>() {
             public Map<String, Double> load(Object key) {
               return source.load();
             }
          };
  double get(String key) {
    return cache.get(KEY).get(key);
  }
}
```